# React.js to display Pusher's captured data/events

Tags: reactjs, pusher

I wanted to integrate events/broadcasting in my laravel API.With trial and error, I have managed to set up my server to trigger an event for every post request. I can ascertain it is working as expected because I can view these events from my pusher account.My frontend is a simple React.js application. After connecting it to pusher, my browser console displays a success connection to my pusher instance/app. Same goes for the events because they are displayed on the console each time an event occurs .Although unsuccessful, I am trying to display these events as a table on my UI like this................

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
const Pusher = require('pusher-js');

class showEvent extends Component{

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tasks:[],
      loading:true

    }
  }
    componentDidMount(){
      console.log("Mounted");
      Pusher.logToConsole=true;

      var pusher = new Pusher('key', {
        cluster:'',
        app_id:id,
        key:'key',
        secret:'sec',
        encrypted:true
      });
      const this2 = this ;
      var channel = pusher.subscribe('events') ;
      channel.bind('event', function (data) {
        const tasks = this2.state.tasks
        tasks.push(data.data)
        this2.setState({tasks:tasks});
       
      });

      // var loading = channel['pusher']['channels']['channels']['events']['pusher']['connection']['callbacks']['_callbacks'];
 
    }

    render() {

        var tasks = this.state.tasks.map((item) => {
                
          return(
            <tr>{item.program_time}
            <td>{item.event}</td>    
            <td>{item.message}</td>
            <td>{item.actual_time}</td>
            <td>{item.display_message}</td>
            </tr>
          )
      });
      

      return (

        <div className='md-col-2' style={{margin:"30px"}}>
           <div className="card">
              
              <div className="card-header">
                  <h4>Event Viewer
                      <Link to={'/'} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end">Monitor Mode</Link>
                          
                    </h4>
                  <div className="row">
                      <table className="table">                          
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Program Time</th>
                              <th>Event</th>
                              <th>Message</th>
                              <th>Actual Time</th>
                              <th>Display Message</th>
                            </tr>        
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                          {tasks}
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      );
  }

}
```

....but I get an empty table instead.If an event is triggered, my browser console displays the event, but my table does not .What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I did some tweaking and got it working. Turns out, the data my `channel.bind` function was returning was correct. So I changed the function a little to:

```
channel.bind('event', function (data) {
  console.log(data['event']);
  const tasks = this2.state.tasks
  tasks.push(data['event'])
  this2.setState({tasks:tasks});
```

In my Laravel API `eventController`, I added a `broadcastAs()` function for my event. Something like:

```
public function broadcastAs(){
    return 'YourEvent';
}
```